# Returning value from C++ into Obj-C?

Tags: iphone, c++, ios

I'm banging my head for a while with how to return a value from some C++ into Obj-C. Here are my files:

**XMLParsing.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class XMLParsing {
    int i;

public:
    int outputAnArray();
};
```

**XMLParsing.cpp**

```
#include "XMLParsing.h"      

int outputAnArray() {

    return 1;
}
```

**MyTest.mm**

```
XMLParsing *parser = new XMLParsing();
parser->outputAnArray();
```

This raises:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm running this in a SenTestCase, if this piece of info helps.

Comment: Don't you have to do, `int XMLParsing::outputAnArray(void) {`

Comment: @myrkos, if you post that as an answer I'll hug you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLParsing.cpp should be like:

```
#include "XMLParsing.h"

int XMLParsing::outputAnArray() {

 return 1;
}
```

Sorry for the late answer.